# Launch multiple EC2 instances in parallel

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to launch a number of EC2 machines in parallel. Until now I was using boto and fabric but the serial execution takes ages to launch and provision them one by one. Is there any alternative solution to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The amazon command line tools support a parameter for number of instances.

```
aws ec2 run-instances help
   --count (string)
      Number of instances to launch. If a single number is provided, it is
      assumed  to  be the minimum to launch (defaults to 1). If a range is
      provided in the form min:max then the first number is interpreted as
      the  minimum  number of instances to launch and the second is inter-
      preted as the maximum number of instances to launch.
```

If you're running the older CLI:

```
ec2-run-instances
 -n, --instance-count MIN[-MAX]
      The number of instances to attempt to launch. May be specified as a
      single integer or as a range (min-max). This specifies the minimum
      and maximum number of instances to attempt to launch. If a single
      integer is specified min and max are both set to that value.
```

Update:  According to the boto ec2 documentation, you can pass in min_count and max_count parameter to the run_instances command, which would also let you start multiple instances in parallel.

Comment: above info does not mention anywhere whether it creates multiple instances "simultaneously" or "one-after-another". OP is looking for an alternative to `serial execution` of multiple instance launch.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer: This is a single command and the instances are created in parallel.

Comment: Agree. Just tried it and it worked. Tried with Ruby SDK as well and it worked. They all are creating instances in parallel as they all are calling the same APIs. Not sure why OP says python boto is not creating instances in parallel. I have never tried Boto. But AWS CLI uses boto behind the curtains.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [CloudFormation](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/cloudformation/) to launch an auto scaling group with fixed size:

```
"MyFixedSizeGroup":{
        "Type":"AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
        "Properties":{
            "LaunchConfigurationName":{"Ref":"GlobalWorkersSmallLaunchConf"},
            "AvailabilityZones" : [ "us-east-1a" ],
            "MinSize":"4",
            "MaxSize":"4",
            "DesiredCapacity":"4",
            "Tags":[{"Key":"Name", "Value":"worker instance", "PropagateAtLaunch":"true"}]          
        }           
}
```

and the desired launch configuration, for example:

```
"GlobalWorkersSmallLaunchConf":{
        "Type":"AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
        "Properties":{"KeyName":{"Ref":"MyKeyName"},
                      "ImageId":"ami-SomeAmi",
                      "UserData":{"Fn::Base64":{"Fn::Join":["",[{"Ref":"SomeInitScript"}]]}},
                      "SecurityGroups":[{"Ref":"InstanceSecurityGroup"}],
                      "InstanceType":"m1.small",
                      "InstanceMonitoring":"false"
        }           
}
```

You can use it with [boto](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/cloudformation.html) or the via the [CLI](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/2555753788650372)

BTW- It performs a lot better because you send a single request to AWS service, that is handled as a stack. to terminate the instances (and any other resources you want to add) just delete the stack.